# SharePoint 2013 - List alerts email notification not always sent

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I've set up an "alert me" rule to send me a notification of every change, instantly.

When I edit an item twice successively, only one alert email is sent.

I'm pretty sure that this is a normal SharePoint behavior, but what I need is an official documentation or explanation about why is this happening.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say that you edit the item twice, how quickly do you do this? Alerts are sent according to the admin timer, which usually only runs every minute, so if you happen to edit the item twice within a minute, the system sees that as one change and so only sends one notification.

Comment: We can say that item is being edited in the next 10 seconds, so yes, only one email is being sent. Do you have any official/unofficial documentation/link/post that explains how Alerts are sent according to the admin timer ? Thanks.